# Socket client (Emulator Android)/ Server (Eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sockets

I have to realize a project for the university, and I want to realize an Android application that connects to a local server on my computer.
I have coded Client and Server classes, but when i run my Client class on my emulator, I have the error:

```
03-23 13:04:47.850 3499-3499/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
03-23 13:04:47.859 3499-3499/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
03-23 13:04:48.036 3499-3504/? E/art: Failed writing handshake bytes (-1 of 14): Broken pipe
03-23 13:04:48.036 3499-3504/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
03-23 13:04:48.037 3499-3504/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
03-23 13:04:48.259 3499-3499/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.flora.drawmyfriend-2/lib/x86
03-23 13:04:48.596 3499-3499/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
03-23 13:04:49.126 3499-3499/com.flora.drawmyfriend I/debug: start
03-23 13:04:49.130 3499-3522/com.flora.drawmyfriend I/debug: Attempting to connect to server
03-23 13:04:49.132 3499-3522/com.flora.drawmyfriend E/debug: Permission denied
03-23 13:04:49.137 3499-3522/com.flora.drawmyfriend E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                      Process: com.flora.drawmyfriend, PID: 3499
                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.InputStream java.net.Socket.getInputStream()' on a null object reference
                                                                          at com.flora.drawmyfriend.MainActivity$MySyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:45)
                                                                          at com.flora.drawmyfriend.MainActivity$MySyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:31)
                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
03-23 13:04:49.175 3499-3499/com.flora.drawmyfriend I/InstantRun: Starting Instant Run Server for com.flora.drawmyfriend
```

I went on all the forum possible to answer my questions, but i couldn't find solutions.
Is it possible that someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

My Client Class Code is :

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int portnumber = 50000;
    private Socket socket=null;
    Socket client = null;
    DataOutputStream dataoutput = null;
    DataInputStream datainput = null;

    private static final String debugString ="debug";

    class MySyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Object... params) {
            try {
                //Connecting
                Log.i(debugString, "Attempting to connect to server");
                client = new Socket("10.0.2.2", portnumber);
                Log.i(debugString, "Connection established");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(debugString, e.getMessage());
            }

            //Ouverture des flux
            try {
                InputStream input = client.getInputStream();
                datainput = new DataInputStream(input);
                OutputStream output = client.getOutputStream();
                dataoutput = new DataOutputStream(output);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Erreur ouverture des flux joueur");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.i(debugString,"start");
        }
    }

    public MainActivity() throws UnknownHostException {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MySyncTask asyncTask=new MySyncTask ();
        asyncTask.execute(1000);
    }


    public void sendMessage (View view)
    {
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String nom = null;
        try {
            //Send message to server
            nom=editText.getText().toString();
            dataoutput.writeUTF(nom);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(debugString, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

and my Server Code on Eclipse (which seems to work):

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
class Joueur {
    Socket joueur = null;
    DataOutputStream dataoutput = null;
    DataInputStream datainput = null;
    String name;
    String mark;
    // Constructeur : ouverture des flux
    Joueur (Socket j) {
        this.joueur = j;
        try {
            InputStream input = j.getInputStream();
            this.datainput = new DataInputStream(input);                
            OutputStream output = j.getOutputStream();
            this.dataoutput = new DataOutputStream(output);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Erreur ouverture des flux serveur");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
public class Main {
    private static final int portnumber = 50000;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ServerSocket serverSocket;
        Socket socket=null;
        try {
            System.out.println("Server starting at port number " + portnumber);
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portnumber);
            //Client connecting
            System.out.println("waiting for clients to connect.");
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("A client has connected");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        Joueur joueur= new Joueur(socket);
        String nom=null;
        try {
            nom = joueur.datainput.readUTF();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(nom);    
    }
}
```

I did the modifications necessary in the Android Manifest.

Thank you in advance for you time!!

Comment: Can you post your full log.

Comment: Have you added the INTERNET permission to your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: Yes I added the internet permission

Comment: `Can you post your full log`. We wait. Please do not just not react.

Comment: `Thank you in advance for you help!!`. So you will not say thank you if you have been helped?

Comment: I added the full log in the post :)

Comment: How about [ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE?](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html)

Comment: I added the permission too in my AndroidManifest

Comment: @Flora `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`